# Small Haskell Hangman game

Tags: game, haskell, hangman

I've been learning Haskell, and a while ago I created this Hangman game. I've been working on using a library for terminal output, so no more hardcoded escape codes, but in the meantime I'd like some comments on what I have until now.

Is this readable, correct Haskell code with no obvious performance problems?

The code depends on a file being present named after the language (EN or NL) containing linebreak-separated words that is easily created.

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Data.Char (isAlpha, toUpper)
import Data.List (intersperse)
import System.IO (hSetBuffering, stdin, BufferMode (NoBuffering) )

lang = EN

main :: IO ()
main = do hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
          f <- readFile $ show lang
          startplaying $ lines f

startplaying :: [String] -> IO ()
startplaying words = do index <- randomRIO (0,length words - 1)
                        playgame (words !! index) []
                        putStrLn $ strings lang Another
                        ans   <- getChar
                        case ans of
                           'n' -> return ()
                           _   -> startplaying words

playgame :: String -> [Char] -> IO ()
playgame word guessed
  | complete                                       = printState word guessed Won ""
  | guessedwrong word guessed >= length hangman -1 = printState word guessed Lost word
  | otherwise                                      = do printState word guessed Pick ""
                                                        l <- fmap toUpper getChar
                                                        let guessed' | not (isAlpha l)  = guessed
                                                                     | l `elem` guessed = guessed
                                                                     | otherwise        = l : guessed
                                                        playgame word guessed'
  where complete :: Bool
        complete = all (`elem` guessed) (map toUpper word)

guessedwrong :: String -> [Char] -> Int
guessedwrong word guessed = length $ filter (`notElem` map toUpper word) guessed

printState :: String -> [Char] -> Message -> String -> IO ()
printState word guessed message string = putStrLn $ "\ESC[2J" ++
                                  unlines [ hangman !! (guessedwrong word guessed)
                                          , map (\x -> if (elem (toUpper x) guessed) then x else '_') word
                                          , (strings lang Used) ++ intersperse ' ' guessed
                                          , strings lang message ++ string
                                          ]

strings :: Language -> Message -> String
strings NL m = case m of
                  Another -> "Wil je nog een keer spelen? [Y/n]"
                  Won     -> "Gefeliciteerd! Je hebt het woord geraden!"
                  Lost    -> "Je bent dood. Het woord was "
                  Pick    -> "Kies een letter"
                  Used    -> "Gebruikte letters: "
strings EN m = case m of
                  Another -> "Play another game? [Y/n]"
                  Won     -> "Congratulations! You got it!"
                  Lost    -> "You're dead. The word was "
                  Pick    -> "Pick a letter"
                  Used    -> "Used letters: "

data Message = Another | Won | Lost | Pick | Used

data Language = NL
              | EN
              deriving (Show)

hangman = [ unlines  [ ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     ]
          , unlines  [ ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , ""
                     , " ___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ ""
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/       |"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/       |"
                     , "|       (_)"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/       |"
                     , "|       (_)"
                     , "|        |"
                     , "|        |"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/       |"
                     , "|       (_)"
                     , "|       /|"
                     , "|        |"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/       |"
                     , "|       (_)"
                     , "|       /|\\"
                     , "|        |"
                     , "|"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/       |"
                     , "|       (_)"
                     , "|       /|\\"
                     , "|        |"
                     , "|       /"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          , unlines  [ "_________"
                     , "|/       |"
                     , "|       (_)"
                     , "|       /|\\"
                     , "|        |"
                     , "|       / \\"
                     , "|"
                     , "|___"
                     ]
          ]
```

Comment: `startplaying words = do index <- randomRIO (0,length words)` should be `startplaying words = do index <- randomRIO (0,length words - 1)` so you don't go off the end of the list.

Comment: Consider failing with a more helpful message if the language-specific file isn't there, perhaps as part of allowing the user to choose the language at start up.

Comment: It suffers from the `getChar` bug in ghc under windows (but is OK in WinHugs, and the fix causes a bug in WinHugs). This might not matter to you. See [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983974/haskell-read-input-character-from-console-immediately-not-after-newline/13370293#13370293)

Comment: @AndrewC: Thank you. I fixed the off-by-one error (d'oh). I was planning on making the language selectable as part of separating the UI code and using a terminal library. I'm aware of the Windows bug, but since this is just a toy program I didn't really worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have so much redundant data in `State`? That just means you have to put a lot of effort into keeping everything up-to-date - which doesn't just make your program longer, but is also prone to mistakes.

By eliminating all redundancy as well as replacing the explicit state variable by control flow, the `playgame` function can be simplified down to pretty much the following:

```
count_duds :: String -> [Char] -> Int
count_duds word guessed = length $ filter (`notElem` map toUpper word) guessed

playgame :: String -> [Char] -> IO ()
playgame word guessed
  | all (`elem` guessed) (map toUpper word)       = putStrLn $ header "Won"
  | count_duds word guessed + 1 >= length hangman = putStrLn $ header "Lost" ++ word
  | otherwise = do putStrLn $ header "Pick"
                   l <- fmap toUpper getChar
                   let guessed' | not (isAlpha l)  = guessed
                                | l `elem` guessed = guessed
                                | otherwise        = l:guessed
                   playgame word guessed'
  where header msg = formatState word guessed ++ "\n" ++ strings lang msg
```

Admittedly, this does quite a bit of re-computation, especially on the "duds". Yet we can probably expect both words and game lengths to be small, therefore it is better to go with a more compact program.

Comment: Thank you! I agree, my version was much too verbose and error-prone. I guess I was subconsciously porting an earlier C# version too literally, which had all these state variables as member variables.

I tried implementing your suggestions myself, in order to learn from them. I changed my code in the question. Do you think I implemented your ideas well?